# How do I use fscanf to read file to initialize values in C?

Tags: c, file

Suppose I have Client.txt file that looks like this.
[Client.txt file picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdO9L.png)

```
1111
Name One
Email.email.1
111-111-1111
2222
Name Two Two
Email.email.2
222-222-2222
3333
Name Three Three
Email.email.3
333-333-3333
```

The Client txt file contains
client's id, name, email, and phone number.

Now the task is to read from the Client file and save id, name, email, and phone number into a struct called Client.
From this Client text file, I will make three struct values which are going to be pushed in to a list of structs.

But since I am just learning how to use fscanf, and in an attempt practice fscanf, I am narrowing the task into:
how to read from text and initialize the first client's values?

Here is what I attempted.

```
int main(void){
    FILE *fPtr;
    if((fPtr = fopen("Client.txt"), "r") == NULL){
        puts("File could not be found.");
    }
    else{
        //First Client
        int clientId;//1111
        char clientName[30];//Name One
        char clientEmail[30];//Email.email.1
        char clientPhone[30];//111-111-1111

        //Initialize the first client.
        fscanf(fPtr, "%d%s%s%s", &clientId, clientName, clientEmail, clientPhone);

        //While not end of the file, initialize rest of the clients.
        while(!feof(fPtr)){
            //Have not yet implemented.
        }
        fclose(fPtr);

    }
}
```

How can I initialize the first client value as

```
 clientId = 1111
 clientName[30] = Name One
 clientEmail[30] = Email.email.1
 clientPhone[30] = 111-111-1111
```

Comment: `%s` matches a single "word" (i.e. a sequence of non white-space characters), so it cannot be used to read a string containing spaces.

Comment: (`f`)`scanf` is very fiddly, and although it tends to be taught early on, in many ways it's not very suitable material for those new to C.  In this case, what you have looks pretty good, except for one issue: strings scanned by a `%s` directive are delimited by whitespace, so you cannot use that to scan strings that contain whitespace, such as the names in your input.

Comment: To read a line at a time, use `fgets` instead of `fscanf` (and then remember to remove the trailing newline that gets read as part of the line).

Comment: I would recommend reading each of the 4 lines (per client) using `fgets` which reads a whole line at a time if the supplied buffer is large enough to hold the entire line including the newline character and a null terminator.

Comment: To skip leading whitespace and then scan everything to the end of a line, use `" %[^\n]"` (do not omit the leading space character).  Note also that scanning strings without specifying a maximum field width should be considered an outright error, for it leaves you wide open to buffer overflow attacks.  So maybe something more like "%d %29[^\n]%29s%29s"`.  That will still give surprising results if the input has overlong fields, but it will not overflow any of your arrays.

Comment: `File could not be found.` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  And you're printing it to the wrong stream.  Use `const char *path = "Client.txt"; if( (fPtr = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL ){ perror(path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`.

Comment: You have incorrectly matched parentheses in `if((fPtr = fopen("Client.txt"), "r") == NULL){` Is the compiler not warning you of this?

Comment: A warning: when reading strings using fscanf, *always* specify the maximum number of characters that may be read, so as to not overrun your buffer (be sure to leave space for the null terminator).  i.e. don't say `char buf[30]; fscanf(stdin, "%s", buf);`. Say `char buf[30]; fscanf(stdin, "%29s", buf);`. Failure to do so creates a bug that permits the person typing the data to [execute arbitrary code](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/fa08/papers/stack_smashing.pdf).

Comment: Also, note that `feof` only returns a true result *after* fscanf (or another stdio function) has attempted and failed to read past the end of the file. So be careful when you finish writing that `while(!feof(fPtr))` loop; it probably won't work the way you expect if you start it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, not using `scanf` but `getline`

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


typedef struct Client_s
{
        int clientId;
        char clientName[30];
        char clientEmail[30];
        char clientPhone[30];
} Client;

Client* get_next_client(FILE *f_ptr)
{
        Client *new_client = malloc(sizeof(Client));
        char *buff = malloc(30);
        size_t size = 30;
        int error = 0;

        if (new_client == NULL || buff == NULL)
                return NULL;

        if (getline(&buff, &size, f_ptr) <= 0)
                return NULL;
        new_client->clientId = atoi(buff);
        if (getline(&buff, &size, f_ptr) <= 0)
                return NULL;
        strncpy(new_client->clientName, buff, strlen(buff) - 1);
        if (getline(&buff, &size, f_ptr) <= 0)
                return NULL;
        strncpy(new_client->clientEmail, buff, strlen(buff) - 1);
        if (getline(&buff, &size, f_ptr) <= 0)
                return NULL;
        strncpy(new_client->clientPhone, buff, strlen(buff) - 1);

        free(buff);
        return new_client;
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
        FILE * f_ptr = fopen("Client.txt", "r");

        if (f_ptr == NULL)
        {
                write(2, "Could not open file\n", strlen("Could not open file\n"));
                return 1;
        }

        Client *client = get_next_client(f_ptr);
        while (client != NULL)
        {
                printf("%d\n", client->clientId);
                //handle client
                client = get_next_client(f_ptr);
        }

        fclose(f_ptr);

        return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to free the recieved Clients when you don't need them anymore.

Hope if fixes your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your response helped me immensely to think about the bigger picture. But, I am implementing this with "fgets" function instead of "getline" function. Do you think using fgets is a bad idea ? or makes no difference ?

Comment: Using `fgets` is fine.  You'll often have to strip the trailing `\n`, though.